# Setting a panel to visible using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, panel

How can I make a `<asp:Panel>` visible using javascript?

I have done the following but get an error (Cannot Read property style of null)

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" id="panNonAfricanCountries" Visible="false">

var panNonAfricaDropDown = document.getElementById("panNonAfricanCountries")
if (dropDownFirst == "Yes") {
    panNonAfricaDropDown.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: make sure your js code run only after document load

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("<%=panNonAfricanCountries.ClientID%>")`? Or adding `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Visible="false"` on an asp.net control **have as result to not render the control** on the page.

What you try to do here is to render it, but with css style to have it hidden from the user until using javascript show it. To archive that do not use the Visible, but set a style or a css to your Panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelId" runat="server" Visible="true" style="visibility:hidden" >
Some Content here...    
</asp:Panel>
```

The `asp.Panel` is render as `div` and your html on the page will probably as:

```
<div id="PanelId" style="visibility:hidden">
Some Content here...    
</div>
```

and I say probably because we do not know for sure how the Id is rendered. To get it we use the `PanelId.ClientID` and your final javascript code will be:

```
var panNonAfricaDropDown = document.getElementById("<%=PanelId.ClientID%>");
if (dropDownFirst == "Yes" && panNonAfricaDropDown) {
    panNonAfricaDropDown.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET mangles the names of elements that run on the server. You will have to find the mangled name and then do document.getElementById on that name.

Alternatively, you can use the ClientIDMode property of asp:panel to turn off the mangling (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)